# Color codes in Io

Tags: iolanguage, color-codes

Is there a special trick to getting Io to switch the colors of terminal text? In Python I can run

`print "\033[0;34;40mHi!"`

and get a blue "Hi!".

In Io,

`"\033[0;34;40mHi!" println`

seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like Io sequences (strings) only convert single (alpha) character escape codes like \n or \t.

So (for now) this maybe the only workaround:

```
27 asCharacter .. "[0;34;40mHi!" println
```